# Ler mensagem do código USSD Android

Tags: java, android

Utilizando a API no Android é possível comunicar via USSD?

É possível de outra forma?

Se sim como posso obter, no Java, a mensagem de resposta quando se introduz um código USSD?

Comment: de uma olhada nesse link, talvez possa ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902185/ussd-on-android-from-applications

Answer (score 1):

Esse link fala de uma forma geral sobre o assunto:

***Onde está a violação de segurança?***

Para executar um código USSD, você deve inseri-lo no teclado do seu telefone e pressionar “Ligar”. O que Borgaonkar descobriu é que este código executa automaticamente em segundo plano, sem que o usuário note que a ação está acontecendo.

Para isso, ele usou um recurso que pertence ao repertório padrão dos smartphones: o link do navegador com o aplicativo de telefone (o discador). Isto é: Se eu digitar no navegador um número de telefone irá abrir diretamente o aplicativo de telefone com o número e só precisamos clicar em “Ligar” para que execute o processo. Para isso, é preciso um código HTML:

```
<a href="tel:xyz">Clique aqui para ligar diretamente</a>
```

Agora podemos substituir perfeitamente o número do telefone "**xyz**" pelo código USSD como ***2767*3855#**, facilmente. Usando nosso exemplo ficaria assim:

> `<a href="tel:*2767*3855#">Clique aqui para ligar diretamente</a>`

O comando acima assume, no entanto, que o usuário clicou em um link, de modo que o aplicativo de telefone dá início. Borgaonkar incorporou este comando em um frame, que se parece com a estrutura abaixo:

```
<frameset><frame src=“tel:*2767*3855#" /></frameset>
```

Se esta estrutura for colocada em um site na Internet, qualquer telefone que acesse esta página ligará imediatamente para este número, sem mais investigação de segurança. Porém, este não é o problema, porque quando vou a um site do tipo malicioso com meu smartphone, o aplicativo de telefone abre, mas tenho explicitamente que toque em "Ligar" para que algo aconteça e execute uma ação.

A falha de segurança é que alguns smartphones não requerem certas interações com o usuário. Em vez disso, a chamada é imediatamente executada no fundo. E se esta chamada de fundo esconde um atalho correspondente para um código USSD, aí é que mora o problema. Na demonstração de Borgaonkar isso significa que o Galaxy S2 pode visitar um site malicioso e começar imediatamente o reset de fábrica sem o usuário sabe o que está acontecendo.

Referência:

http://www.androidpit.com.br/ussd-exploit